# Python 3 Tkinter : Popup not displaying

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a 2 popups triggered  by the same button : One have a progress bar, a label and a button. The other only have 2 labels and a button. If I comment the update function of the progress bar : neither of the popup is displayed. If I try to only display the second (without progress bar) it doesn't display. I can only display both at the same time and I want only to display the second one (without progress bar)

Here is the code of the first popup :

```
def sim_process_bar(self):
        self.popup_process = Tk()
        self.popup_process.wm_title("Simulation process...")
        self.progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(self.popup_process, orient = 'horizontal', length = 286, mode = 'determinate')
        self.progressBar['maximum'] = 100
        self.stopBtn = Button(self.popup_process, text="Stop Simulation", command = self.popup_process.destroy)
        self.progressBar.grid(column = 1, row = 1, pady = 10)
        self.stopBtn.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

        self.labelPercentage = Label(self.popup_process, text="Percentage complete : 0% ")
        self.labelPercentage.grid(column = 1, row = 3, pady = 10)

    def update_value_process_bar(self, value):
        self.progressBar['value'] = value
        self.progressBar.update()
```

The code of the second popup :

```
def process_feedback(self):
        self.popupFeedback = Tk()
        self.popupFeedback.wm_title("Simulation process...")
        self.labelTimestep = Label(self.popupFeedback, text="Current timestep : ")
        self.labelTimestep.grid(column = 0 , row = 1, pady = 10)

        self.labelPercentage2 = Label(self.popupFeedback, text="Percentage complete : ")
        self.labelPercentage2.grid(column = 0, row = 2, pady = 10)

        self.Btnstop = Button(self.popupFeedback, text="Stop Simulation", command = self.popupFeedback.destroy)
        self.Btnstop.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
```

I call the function at the just before the beggining of a loop and then update values inside this same loop :

the update :

```
if(round(k/self.total_timestep_of_simulation*100,1).is_integer()):
    self.update_value_process_bar(k/self.total_timestep_of_simulation*100)
    self.labelPercentage['text'] = "Percentage complete : " + str(round(k/self.total_timestep_of_simulation*100,1)) + "%"
#UPDATE POPUP FEEDBACK
self.labelTimestep['text'] = "Current timestep : " + str(data_update.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S"))
self.labelPercentage2['text'] = "Percentage complete : " + str(round(k/self.total_timestep_of_simulation*100,1)) + "%"
```

so if I comment the "self.update_value"... function, nothing shows up on screen and if I only try to display the second one nothing shows up neither. I'm sure it's a dumb problem, but I'm struggling with this...

Comment: Multiple instances of `Tk()` cause all sorts of problems.  Try using `Toplevel()` instead for your popups - that way, everything lives in a single Tk instance, and a single `.update()` (or actively running `.mainloop()`) will process events for all the windows.

Comment: I tried to use Toplevel, but it doesn't change anything, unfortunately..

Answer (score -1):

Your code is ok, but try to remove the line `self.stopBtn = Button(self...` or replace it by

```
    self.stopButton = Button(self.popup_process,
                             text="Stop Simulation",
                             command = self.destroy_popup)
```

and add

```
def destroy_popup(self):
    self.popup_process.destroy()
```

And same for the other popup:

```
    self.Btnstop = Button(self.popupFeedback,
                          text="Stop Simulation",
                          command = self.destroy_popup)
    ...

def destroy_popup(self):
    self.popupFeedback.destroy()
```

Sometimes the button "makes the connection" to the control to which it is attached. In this example, `self.popup_process.destroy` is a loop contained in `Tkinter` module. So the button executes that command. Putting it in a `def` avoids this.

That is only valid for certain versions. Maybe the one you're using is one of them. Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: An other way to do this: 1. in `def destroy_popup`, put `self.popup_process.destroy` in `if self.destroy:`; 2. put `self.destroy` at `False` just before adding the button; 3. put `self.destroy` at `True` after packing the button. `self.destroy` put at `False` disable destroying the window, and putting it at `True` allow destroying when the button will be clicked.